# Magento 2 - Reauth/Revalidate the Customer Password after placing the order

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, order-status, password

Revalidate the logged-in customer's password after placing the order, once the password is correct, order status is changed to *"New Status"* till that it will in *"Pending"* status on Admin.

Is there any possible way to validate the customer's password after placing an order?

Answer (score 0):

The below explained to add the reauth of logged-in customer anywhere on the site.

[Magento 2 - check if customer password is set to a specific value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221263/magento-2-check-if-customer-password-is-set-to-a-specific-value/#answer-221338)